# skip all ModelForm validation conditionally but include it all otherwise

Tags: validation, django-1.4

I have a form that has a selector at the top where a user can select none, or choose a couple options where the validation varies depending on the selection.

If they select none, then it needs to save the model ignoring all the fields and just putting in "None" for the one option.  If they select one of the others, then it needs to preform validation on all the other fields.

The thing is, the only way for me to get it to save when "None" is selected, is if I set blank=True on all the fields for the model.  So I basically have to turn off all the validation.
But then when they select something, I override the clear method and have to do all the validation manually...

Is there any way for me to use all the built in validation based on the option?  In other frameworks I've used, there's an array full of rules, and I can just modify that based on whatever and then run the rules automatically off that array.

Is there a method before the clean, clean_fieldname, and any other validation where I can grab the one selected option, and modify the rules for everything else based on it before it does the build in validation?

I just can't seem to figure out how to use the validation in a versatile way in Django.  It seems that if I'm not using them in one specific scenario, it falls down to having to do it all manually.  I am fairly new to it, so I'm likely missing something.

Thanks